# -XX:MaxNewSize and other JVM parameter setting in AIX

Tags: performance, memory, aix, websphere, java

All,
I am trying to adjust our application's memory settings: JVM and Heap adjustments. I also came across -XX:MaxNewSize parameter.
Our application runs on a AIX machine which has ample RAM (100+ GB). 1200 concurrent users. Deployed in WAS 6.1

My question is: 
-XX:MaxNewSize - What is this param used for? Is this parameter applicable for AIX?
I also need some assistance in increasing JVM size (-XX:MaxPermSize param). Our current value is 256 MB. For an application which has peak load of about 1300 concurrent users, do we need to increase this param to 512 MB? Reason is our application nodes go down due to out of memory issues. Out max and min heap size is 1.5 GB

Edit: Also, if you could provide JVM memory architecture, it would be even more helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Which JDK is it using? The JVM's parameters are dependent on the type of JDK used, and not the OS.

Comment: java version "1.5.0"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build pap32dev-20080315 (SR7))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.3, J2RE 1.5.0 IBM J9 2.3 AIX ppc-32 j9vmap3223-20080315 (JIT enabled)
J9VM - 20080314_17962_bHdSMr
JIT  - 20080130_0718ifx2_r8
GC   - 200802_08)
JCL  - 20080314

Answer (score 1):

WebSphere 6.1 uses Java 5. On AIX, it uses IBM's Java 5. Based on [this documentation of the IBM J2SE 5 command-line options](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v5r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.java.doc.user.aix32.50/diag/appendixes/cmdline/commands_jvm_xx.html), I'd say `-XX:MaxNewSize` is not supported.

However, you can certainly increase the maximum heap size through the Admin Console (which sets the `-Xmx` option), and if you have sufficient RAM that's a perfectly valid thing to do.

`Servers` > `Application servers` > your-server-name > `Server Infrastructure` > `Java and Process Management` > `Process Definition` > `Java Virtual Machine` > `Maximum Heap Size`

Comment: yes it is using Java 5, but how about increasing JVM to 512 MB (from 256). What are the impacts?

Comment: Increasing `-Xmx`, the JVM will use more physical memory (RAM) for heap space. Make sure you have enough free physical memory.